# Problems with COUNT function in SQL Server when using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server

I am getting incorrect count values when I include an INNER JOIN to add the Version column that matches the Uri from a different table.

**Data**

Table `Downloads`

| id | IP | Uri | response | datetimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111.222.223.224 | /server1/alpha/product.exe | 200 | 20220601 00:02:03 |
| 2 | 100.101.101.200 | /server1/beta/product.exe | 200 | 20220601 00:05:30 |
| 3 | 104.103.100.101 | /server1/alpha/product.exe | 200 | 20220601 14:00:15 |
| 4 | 111.222.223.224 | /server1/alpha/product.exe | 200 | 20220601 20:30:00 |
| 5 | 104.103.100.101 | /server1/beta/product.exe | 400 | 20220601 23:00:04 |
| 6 | 98.100.001.120 | /server1/alpha/product.exe | 200 | 20220601 13:30:00 |

Table `Versions`:

| Uri | Version |
| --- | --- |
| /server1/alpha/product.exe | 1.0.0 |
| /server1/beta/product.exe | 2.0.0 |

SQL statements

I get the proper COUNT when I omit the version from the results

Working `Select`:

```
SELECT IP, COUNT(IP) AS Downloads
FROM Downloads Data
WHERE Uri LIKE '%alpha%' 
  AND Response = '200' 
  AND (Date BETWEEN '20220601 00:00:00' AND '20220602 00:00:00')
GROUP BY IP
ORDER BY COUNT(IP) DESC
```

When adding the `INNER JOIN` to add the `Version` information, I get bad data

Not working `Select`:

```
SELECT 
    dlData.IP, dlData.Uri, verData.Version, 
    COUNT(dlData.IP) AS Downloads
FROM 
    Downloads dlData
INNER JOIN 
    Versions verData ON verData.Uri = dlData.Uri
WHERE 
    dlData.Uri LIKE '%alpha%' 
    AND Response = '200' 
    AND (Date BETWEEN '20220601 00:00:00' AND '20220602 00:00:00')
GROUP BY 
    IP, dlData.Uri, verData.Version
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(dlData.IP) DESC
```

Results

Working `Select`:

| IP | Downloads |
| --- | --- |
| 111.222.223.224 | 3046 |
| 100.101.101.200 | 2195 |
| 104.103.100.101 | 1998 |
| 98.100.001.120 | 1608 |

Not working `Select`:

| IP | Uri | Version | Downloads |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111.222.223.224 | /server1/alpha/product.exe | 1.0.0 | 12184 |
| 100.101.101.200 | /server1/alpha/product.exe | 1.0.0 | 7952 |
| 104.103.100.101 | /server1/alpha/product.exe | 1.0.0 | 4374 |
| 98.100.001.120 | /server1/beta/product.exe | 2.0.0 | 4016 |

Really appreciate any help as I have been stuck for days not finding anything that matched on SO and other search results. This seems like a fairly standard operation to perform on data.

Comment: This is copied from another comment I made today, but the same applies: *"Sounds like you have a many to one relationship and you expect SQL Server to only `COUNT`/`SUM` a row once, when it's returned multiple times. That isn't how aggregate functions work. Likely you need to pre-aggregate.* I would suggest using a Derived Table or CTE to pre-aggregate, and then `JOIN` to your table that has the one-to-many relationship that is causing the results you don't expect.

Comment: did you try left join?

Comment: @Larnu, I did try something like what you are describing, but I am at a loss of how the next level of complexity with using statement results for another statement works.

Comment: @TayfunYuksel LEFT JOIN yields same results

Comment: It would be *one* statement, @WalterWojciechowski , not 2.

Comment: @Walter Wojciechowski did you try without date

Comment: @TayfunYuksel yes without Date its still not correct

Comment: The `Versions` table does not have a unique identifier. So, each record from the `Downloads` table is related to several records from the `Versions` table. You can't get the right number. You must use a field that is unique. You can add the start date and end date fields in the `Versions` table and use them in join.

Comment: @MostafaNZ I can guarantee the Uri entries in Versions table are unique.

Comment: Sorry. If what you say is true. The output of your code will also be correct. Or you have not provided correct information about the structure of the tables. [The code you provided](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6c1ab/3) .In your code there is this condition `dlData.Uri LIKE '%alpha%'` . But there is `/server1/beta/product.exe` in the output. which are not consistent with each other

Comment: @MostafaNZ correct, because I want the count of only the alpha downloads, ignoring the beta downloads.

Comment: thanks everyone for help, @Larnu your comment sent me down the CTE road and that helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected:

```
WITH
    alpha_downloads AS (

    SELECT 
        dlData.IP, dlData.Uri, COUNT(dlData.IP) AS Downloads
    FROM 
        Downloads dlData
    WHERE 
        dlData.Uri LIKE '%alpha%' 
        AND Response = '200' 
        AND (Date BETWEEN '20220601 00:00:00' AND '20220602 00:00:00')
    GROUP BY 
        dlData.IP, dlData.Uri
)

SELECT
    alpha_downloads.ClientIP,alpha_downloads.Uri,
    verData.Version,alpha_downloads.Downloads
FROM
    alpha_downloads
INNER JOIN
    tblVersions verData ON verData.Uri=alpha_downloads.Uri
GROUP BY 
    alpha_downloads.Downloads,alpha_downloads.ClientIP,
    alpha_downloads.Uri,verData.Version
ORDER BY
    alpha_downloads.Downloads DESC
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).